# Why is my onCreateView method being called twice?

Tags: android, android-activity, oncreate

While debugging another issue, I realized that the `onCreateView` method of one of my **activities** was being called twice.  I'm new to programming and I don't fully understand how `android` calls these methods when the **activity** loads, but it doesn't seem right to me that it would be called twice. Eliminating most of my code, I still see my `System.out` message twice.

```
public class AddCourse extends ActionBarActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_course);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new AddCourseFragment()).commit();
        }
    }

    public static class AddCourseFragment extends Fragment {

        View rootView;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_add_course,
                container, false);
                        System.out.println("I see this TWICE!!!!");
            return rootView;
        }       
    }
}
```

This is almost exactly like my main activity implementation, but that one doesn't go through `onCreateView` twice. Thoughts?

My **activity_add_course** xml was requested...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <fragment android:name="com.NsouthProductions.gradetrackerpro.AddCourse$AddCourseFragment"
         android:id="@+id/AddCourseFrag" 
         android:layout_width="match_parent"
         android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you share your activity_add_course layout file?

Comment: @adavis , I've added the layout file.
Is this happening because the layout file basically calls my fragment class? How should I stop it from being called twice?

Comment: looks like you're adding the fragment twice.  If you declare it in the xml then you don't need to add it programmatically as well.

Comment: @adavis , hmm so which part of my code do I remove it from? How can I handle a null savedInstanceState without calling my fragment twice? Sorry, I'm still trying to grasp some of these basics.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Looks like you're adding the fragment twice. If you declare it in the xml then you don't need to add it programmatically as well.

You can **remove** this from your **Activity's** `onCreate()`:

```
if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new AddCourseFragment()).commit();
        }
```

Comment: Thank you. After writing a long question here, I finally inferred that the savedInstanceState condition code is to ensure that the fragment gets inflated. But since the main layout inflates it anyway, this code isn't needed. I hope there are no other side effects. Thanks!