# Android spinner overwriting default selection

Tags: android, android-spinner

I have a spinner with the list of pet types. I want the original text to be replaced by the new selection from the drop down menu, but as seen in the 3rd snapshot below the new text is overwriting the original text.  Following screen shots will explain the scenario better.

[image: Image when drop down is not selected]

[image: Image with drop down expanded]

[image: Image where drop down selection is overwriting the original text]

Following is the code snippet.

```
    ArrayList<String> petDropDownList = new ArrayList<String>();
    petDropDownList.add(0, "CAT");
    petDropDownList.add(1, "DOG");
    petDropDownList.add(2, "HORSE");
    petDropDownList.add(3, "COW");
    final Spinner petTypeSelect = (Spinner)rootView.findViewById(R.id.pet_type_spinner);
    final ArrayAdapter<String> spinnerAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getContext(),
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        petDropDownList);
    petTypeSelect.setAdapter(spinnerAdapter);
    petTypeSelect.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                // ??
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> adapterView) {
                // ??
            }
        });
```

What is the best way to handle this scenario?

Comment: Show your layout file having spinner.

Comment: <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerPadding="20.0sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
        <Spinner
            android:id="@+id/pet_type_spinner"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:textSize="18sp"/>

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days of debugging I realised that the problem was with the double invocation of the fragment class. Here is how I figured out the issue.

1. I put logs in all the relevant methods and I figured out that the onCreate() was being invoked twice.
2. I found the solution to the problem here [Why is my onCreateView method being called twice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22926393/why-is-my-oncreateview-method-being-called-twice)

To summarise the issue, the dropdown appeared to overwrite the previous selection always. In order to fix this issue, I had to remove the double instantiation of the fragment. I had created one in the xml and the other in Activity class. I removed one and the issue was fixed.