# setText method does not work inside the onViewCreated method

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-navigation

**DetailsFragment -> onCreateView**

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    if (fragmentBinding == null)
        fragmentBinding = FragmentDetails.inflate(inflater, container, false);
    return fragmentBinding.getRoot();
}
```

**DetailsFragment -> onViewCreated**

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable @org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    int x = new Random().nextInt(10000);
    Log.w("Result", "... " + x);
    fragmentBinding.titleEditText.setText(String.valueOf(x));

}
```

When open `DetailsFragment` for the first time, `titleEditText` will take the generated number from the `x` variable (Let's suppose it `528`)

Inside `DetailsFragment` there is a button that will navigate me to the `BFragment` fragment.

When navigating to the `BFragment` fragment and doing some tasks, I will press the back button for back to `DetailsFragment`

**What do I expect the result?**

When back from `BFragment` to `DetailsFragment` the  `x` variable will take a new random number (Let's suppose it `362`) and put it inside `titleEditText`.

**What is the current result?**

The text inside `titleEditText` still have `528` value but it must take `362` value

**Notes**

- It's working well if I put the code inside the `onResume` method.
- I'm using the navigation component library with backstack.

---

**Improved the question (Added more details)**

I built a simple app with 2 fragments to show you my problem

Watch the result via the [video](https://streamable.com/npzkjl) on streamable.com, [Mr
Cheticamp](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6287910/cheticamp), If the video doesn't work tell me and I'll upload it to Youtube.

**Here is the Logcat when running the app for the first time**

[image]

**And this is the Logcat when back from SecondFragment to FirstFragment**

[image]

**Here is the code for FirstFragment**

```
public class FirstFragment extends Fragment {

    private FragmentFirstBinding fragmentFirstBinding;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Log.w("FirstFragment", "onCreate");
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        Log.w("FirstFragment", "onCreateView");
        if (fragmentFirstBinding == null)
            fragmentFirstBinding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);
        return fragmentFirstBinding.getRoot();
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        Log.w("FirstFragment", "onViewCreated");

        fragmentFirstBinding.btnFirst.setOnClickListener(view1 -> Navigation.findNavController(view1).navigate(FirstFragmentDirections.actionFirstFragmentToSecondFragment()));

        int x = new Random().nextInt(10000);
        fragmentFirstBinding.edittext.setText(String.valueOf(x));
        Log.w("FirstFragment - X Value", "... " + x);
    }

}
```

**And here is the code for SecondFragment**

```
public class SecondFragment extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_second, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        view.findViewById(R.id.btnSecond).setOnClickListener(view1 -> Navigation.findNavController(view1).popBackStack());
    }

}
```

Comment: When going "back", `onViewCreated()` is not called. See [Fragment lifecycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/lifecycle).

Comment: @Cheticamp But the `onViewCreated` method will be called twice (First Time & When Return From The Back Stack). I tested it by myself. Did I miss something?

Comment: Are you sure it's called when returning from back stack? Does your log show that? Set a breakpoint to examine it.

Comment: @Cheticamp To be honest, I don't know how to use breakpoint yet but I'll create a new simple project with 2 fragments and I'll show you via the video Logcat and emulator, Just give me 30 minutes. Thanks for your patience

Comment: @Cheticamp Mr Cheticamp, Check the update. Sorry for late.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you are conditionally inflating the layout? (i.e. `if (fragmentFirstBinding == null)`). What happens if you do it unconditionally?

Comment: @Michael Okay, there is the reason for that, Look at my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71612483/is-there-any-way-to-avoid-calling-the-oncreateview-method-when-back-to-the-previ) that was published 2 days ago. After a lot of searches, I found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22926575/17839308) and it's working fine.

Comment: @Michael The answer that I linked in my previous reply was wrong and I cannot modify my reply so I was mean this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56615160/17839308)

Comment: My first comment was mistaken, as you know: `onViewCreated()` **is** called after returning from the backstack. I think that @Michael is onto the problem. It looks to me like you are, somehow, referencing one inflated layout while another is showing.

Comment: @Cheticamp @Michael I removed the condition inside the `onCreateView` method and the same problem. The strangest of that is when I put this command `Log.w("FirstFragment", String.valueOf(fragmentFirstBinding.edittext.getText()));` inside the `onViewCreated` method, It prints the new value always but the problem is the value not showing in `EditText` and It must show. Anyway thank you guys for your helping me and if you want to discover the problem on your device you can find the codes above. If I find the problem I'll post it as the answer in the future (If I remember that). Thank you again.

Comment: If you are still looking for assistance, posting your navigation graph might be helpful. I still think that you are ending up with two instantiations of the first fragment. Not sure how that is happening unless it is with the navigation component.